# Even though the Managed bean contains method, server throwing message as does not have the property 'getCustomerDetails'

Tags: java, jsf

iam working on JSF application, even thought the managed bean has the method, but server throwing message as 
[image]

Below is the Managed bean code.

```
package retail.web.mbean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


import retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote;
import retail.model.vo.Customer;


@ManagedBean
public class CustomerMB implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4402277663508618618L;
    private Customer customer = new Customer();
    public void CustomerMB(){
        System.out.println("customer method +++++++++++++++++++++++"+getCustomer());
    }

private List<Customer> customerList;


public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}



public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}



public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return customerList;
}



public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    this.customerList = customerList;
}



public String createCustomer() throws NamingException{
    try{
    System.out.println("in Create customer method +++++++++++++++++++++++");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    //p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
    p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
    p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700"); //any configured port different from 3700 - 34513
    InitialContext c = new InitialContext(p);
    System.out.println("in Create customer method remote+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    CustomerSessionBeanRemote remote = (CustomerSessionBeanRemote) c.lookup("java:global/RetailProducts/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote");
                                                                            //java:global/RetailService/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote
     //java:global/RetailProducts/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote
    System.out.println("in Create customer method remote222+++++++++++++++++++++++");
    remote.insterCustomerDetails(getCustomer());
    remote.showCustDetails();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.exit(1);
    return "viewCustomerDetails";
}

public void getCustomerDetails(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    //List<Customer> customer = null;
    try{
        System.out.println("in Create customer method +++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        //p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
        p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
        p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
        p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700"); //any configured port different from 3700 - 34513
        InitialContext c = new InitialContext(p);
        System.out.println("in Create customer method remote+++++++++++++++++++++++");
        CustomerSessionBeanRemote remote = (CustomerSessionBeanRemote) c.lookup("java:global/RetailProducts/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote");
                                                                                //java:global/RetailService/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote
         //java:global/RetailProducts/CustomerSessionBeanImpl!retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanRemote
        System.out.println("in Create customer method remote222+++++++++++++++++++++++");
        //remote.insterCustomerDetails(getCustomer());
        //customer = remote.showCustDetails();
        setCustomerList(remote.showCustDetails());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.exit(1);
    //  return customer;

}
}
```

**xhtml page**

```
<h:form id="hidden" style="display:none">
        <h:commandLink id="link">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{customer.getCustomerDetails}"/>

        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
   <managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>customer</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>retail.web.mbean.CustomerMB</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: The code looks alright, just tested locally. Try clearing the cache of the Application server. If Tomcat, delete the ${CATALINA_HOME}\work\Catalina\localhost\<your web-app>. May be the class didn't update.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with faces before.
I think the problem is how you are trying to access you methods...
Try changing

```
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{customer.getCustomerDetails}"/>
```

TO

```
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{customer.getCustomerDetails(...)}"/>
```

OR maybe (if faces does some magic)

```
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{customer.customerDetails}"/>
```

Comment: Just did some local testing and it turns out that JSF is intelligent enough to fetch function. By default it will try to search for no-arg function if that's not found. Then it tries to check for function with AjaxBehaviorEvent as an arg.

Comment: Please experiment yourself first before posting random guesses. Otherwise, better post a comment if you can't be sure. If the OP confirms that it works, you can always repost it later as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid. The exception just indicates that the EL expression is been interpreted as part of template text like as would happen in `<p>#{customer.getCustomerDetails}</p>`. The expression is just been evaluated as a value expression during rendering of the page instead of a method expression. A value expression requires a getter method which however doesn't exist in your particular case.

This in turn suggests that the `<f:xxx>` namespace is nowhere registered and thus the `<f:ajax>` is not interpreted as a tag, but as "plain HTML".

To fix it, make sure that you've the JSF core XML namespace declaration in the XML root element:

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're mixing `@ManagedBean` on class and `<managed-bean>` in `faces-config.xml`. I'm not sure why you're doing that, but another possible reason reason would be that you're mixing JSF 1.x with 2.x and thus `@ManagedBean` didn't work for you at all (and thus you're forced to take the old JSF 1.x path of registering it in XML), which implies that the `<f:ajax>` also won't be interpreted as a JSF tag as that didn't exist in JSF 1.x.